# How to silence Slack's default slackbot?

Tags: slack

I'm using Slack with Ubuntu Linux 16.04. While I enjoy working with Slack, there is this annoying Slackbot, which keeps repeating the same messages all the time (for example: *'User is in Do not Disturb mode...'*).

How can I tell Slackbot to stuff off forever?

Comment: Slackbot is a global admin setting. The messages are either controlled by everyone or just restricted to administrators - depending on your Team security settings. But the messages are global across all channels of the Team, so you can't turn them off locally in a specific channel. see https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/202026038-Slackbot-your-assistant-notepad-programmable-bot

Comment: Thanks for reply. Shutting slackbot off in all channels is actually what I'm after. I've already removed the 'x' in `Slackbot Responses` >> `[ ] Enable Slackbot Responses`. However, this bot keeps annoying everybody with the ever same messages ...

Answer (score 16):

It looks like you can't disable Slackbot for all channels, [according to Slack support](https://twitter.com/slackhq/status/813799142833192960?lang=en).

But you can at least disable the channel suggestions by selecting the option of "No, Turn Them Off" under these suggestions, or go to Preferences > Advanced > Other Options and untick the option to send these occasionally.

Comment: This option does exist. Just turned it off - thank you!

Comment: This option no longer exists, but I do see the option to turn off surveys.

Answer (score 7):

While you can't disable Slackbot for any particular channel, if you have permission to delete Slackbot's messages, you can install [this bot](https://github.com/UnitedIncome/slackbot-destroyer), which will delete Slackbot's automated responses for you.

Answer (score 4):

I solved this by reading Slack using an IRC client and this IRC gateway: https://github.com/42wim/matterircd

Then it's just a matter of putting slackbot in my IRC client's IGNORE list.  Et voila!

Answer (score 3):

As of Jan. 21, 2020:

"Note: You can't turn off Slackbot. If you're having trouble with too many messages or custom responses, please speak to your Workspace Admins for help."

- https://slack.com/help/articles/202026038
  [image: screenshot]